# node js request module - how to trace redirects?

Tags: node.js, redirect, request

Lets suppose I want to get some page and when server get my request, it redirect me few times. How to detect those redirects when using request? I would like to see full redirection path if this is possible.

Also I notice that when I visit some pages - I'm redirected from somepage.com/blah to somepage.com and the status is 200? How?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan)  on your express server and use the following code :

```
`app.use(morgan('dev'));`
```

This will log all the get and post requests to your console.

Comment: Thanks there are also https://github.com/olalonde/follow-redirects and https://github.com/jksolbakken/linkfollower. But isn't there simply command for request?

Comment: You're welcome,If you only want the redirected/requested url then just use   console.log(request.url );  , but I still suggest Morgan as it's more comprehensive

Comment: By response.request.uri.href I got only the latest (final) redirect. I want to know all redirect (like: mypage.com/test -> mypage.com/test2 -> mypage.com/test3)

Comment: `var http=require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request,result){

if(request.method == 'GET' || resquest.method == 'POST'){

console.log(request.url);
}
}).listen(3000);

`

Comment: this is a simple server that shows all requests. let me know if it helped ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna test it as soon as I'm near any computer. BTW I'm not using http but request module - error, response, body.